# Load Address Book Contact Image to collection view cell

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to retrieve the user contact information from the address book and load in a collection view cell.
I don't have any problem to retrieve the user name and phone, but I don't know how to load the image to the collection view

Username works, phone works.
Below you have the function that retrieve the username and user phone.

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    // You can fetch selected name and number in the following way

    // user name
    let userName:String = contact.givenName

    // user phone number
    let userPhoneNumbers:[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] = contact.phoneNumbers
    let firstPhoneNumber:CNPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumbers[0].value

  //  let userImage =


    // user phone number string
    let primaryPhoneNumberStr:String = firstPhoneNumber.stringValue

   // print(primaryPhoneNumberStr)
   // print(userName)

    save(name: userName, nameKey: "name", phone: primaryPhoneNumberStr, phoneKey: "phone")


}
```

Can anyone help me to load the picture using this function?

Answer (score 0):

Check if an image is available and assign it to a constant.

```
if contact.imageDataAvailable {
    let yourImage = UIImage(data: contact.imageData)
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact